# Space in function name in prototype

Tags: .net, c++11, winapi

Looking through a source code I found online,there were a group of functions which incorporated inline assembly and their prototype in the file header was quite peculiar, nothing I have ever seen till now, a space in the name of the prototype like this:

```
 DWORD64 ASM_INTERNAL_DEF _mul64(DWORD64 dwA, DWORD64 dwB);
```

And this function was called somewhere in the program like this:

```
(IntType)Math::_mul64(v, 8)
```

Notice `how _mul64` was called from the math namespace without the `ASM_INTERNAL_DEF`.

Can the more seasone programmers elighten me?

Thanks.

I will like to add that for now codeblocks is telling me is an error, but the fact that `_mul64` was called without the first part of the name makes me think there is more to it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no space in the function name.

The function name is `_mul64`.

`DWORD64` is a macro defined as `__int64`.

`ASM_INTERNAL_DEF` is most probably a macro also but I'm not sure what it's defined as.

So this is the same as declaring the function as:

`__int64 ASM_INTERNAL_DEF _mul64(__int64 dwA, __int64 dwB);`

Which is a function that returns an `__int64` and takes 2 `__int64` arguments.

Comment: so lets assume that ASM_INTERNAL_DEF is a macro..but what convention of c++ is this that has a 
return_type macro function_name(parameters) , is this trick possible? does it has a particular name?

Comment: As @IInspectable has mentioned in his answer that ASM_INTERNAL_DEF is most likely to be the calling convention of the function. Therefore the function declaration is valid C++.

Answer (score 1):

There is no space in the function name. The function is called `_mul64`, with return type `DWORD64` (a typedef for `unsigned __int64` as explained under [Windows Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx)), taking 2 `DWORD64` arguments.

`ASM_INTERNAL_DEF` is likely the [calling convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx) implemented by `_mul64`. This is necessary decoration when calling from languages like C or C++, to give the compiler a chance to set up the function call properly (passing arguments and performing cleanup).

The calling convention modifier is usually implemented as a macro in library code, so that it can adapt to external settings (like that target architecture or compiler). When compiling for an x86 platform, both [__stdcall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93.aspx) and [__cdecl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkwh89ks.aspx) are common calling conventions. For x64 there is only one calling convention. It is implied and not spelled out explicitly. In that case the macro expands to nothing.

When calling this function, you can ignore the macro. It is meant for the compiler only. A function call would look like this:

```
DWORD64 arg1 = 42, arg2 = 7;
DWORD64 result = _mul64(arg1, arg2);
```

---

*Note: Calling convention modifiers are not part of the C or C++ Language Specifications. They are always compiler-specific extensions.*

Comment: so lets assume that ASM_INTERNAL_DEF is a macro..but what convention of c++ is this that has a return_type macro function_name(parameters) , is this trick possible? does it has a particular name?

Comment: @user3374754: A macro is never a return type. The compiler doesn't even see the macro; it is expanded by the preprocessor in the early translation phases. It probably expands to either `__stdcall` or `__cdecl` for 32-bit targets, and nothing for 64-bit targets.

Comment: @user3374754: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You should also consider taking the [tour].